# $aggregate $project and $concat values from different collections to a new field

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have two collections running in side a version 3.2.6 instance of MongoDB:

- ManufacturerDevices
- Manufacturers

I'm using an aggregate function to join them:

```
db.ManufacturerDevices.aggregate([
       { $lookup: {
         from: 'Manufacturers',
         localField: 'manufacturer_id',
         foreignField: '_id',
         as: 'manufacturer',
       }},

       { $project: {
         _id: true,
         name: true,
         images: true,
         device_id: true,
         device_name: true,
         // Returns an array
         manufacturer_name: "$manufacturer.manufacturer_name",

       }},

       { $limit: 1 }
]);
```

This works as expected, except that `manufacturer_name` is being returned as an [array] where I was sort of expecting a string.

The issue this is causing me is a little further down the line, where I would like to concatenate `device_name` and `manufacturer_name` into a new field called `'complete_device'`:

```
complete_device: {
    $concat: [
        "$manufacturer.manufacturer_name",
        "$name"
    ]
}
```

Unsurprisingly this returns the error

> "errmsg" : "$concat only supports strings, not Array".

I have tried to use the `$slice` function to return the 0 index value of `"$manufacturer.manufacturer_name"`:

```
{$slice: ["$manufacturer.manufacturer_name", 1]}
```

But this also returns array, causing the same error.

How can I access/return `"$manufacturer.manufacturer_name"` as a string to use in my `$cat` logic?

Comment: You can also use{ $unwind : "$manufacturer"} to convert array to object and then concat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the $arrayElemAt operator

so your query should be

```
complete_device: {
   $concat:[
      {
         $arrayElemAt:[
            "$manufacturer.manufacturer_name",
            0
         ]
      },
      "$name"
   ]
}
```

Comment: p.s. I did upvote but alas my priviliages are noob status!

Comment: @ZaidCrowe You don't necessarily need any privileges in order to accept an answer. You can consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.